# Query date range for date saved in a text field in IBM Notes and Domino

Tags: date, lotus-domino

There is a date saved in a text field. I'm trying to get documents collection when the field is in a date range using `db.FTSearch` method. But `>` and `<` doesn't work in a text field. Are there any way to convert text field? I'm not familiar with IBM Domino and have tried `@TextToTime` but doesn't work.

Comment: lotus API is a pain...what does your query look like?...does the date field have ALL dates in it...if not...why is the data type not a date?...if its not all dates that might be a problem

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. The request like (FIELD field1>=01/01/2018 AND FIELD field1<=01/19/2018)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few ways:

1. use db.Search instead of db.FTSearch; the syntax is completely different though, plus it is rather slow, but if you have to execute your query once per day or even less, you're fine
2. write an agent that converts the text date fields into new real date fields, so you can do your FTSearch; make sure you adapt the form used to create the documents, so that it also creates those date fields
3. use a view, where the first 2 columns contain the date value of your text fields, and sort the view; you'd have to use getDocumentByKey (but I'm not sure this works)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Your date is stored as text, so you need to use [@TextToTime()](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_TEXTTOTIME.html).

I.e.,

```
 FIELD @TextToTime(field1) >= [01/01/2018] AND
 FIELD @TextToTime(field1) <= [01/19/2018]
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I tried FIELD @TextToTime(field1) >= [01/01/2018] AND FIELD @TextToTime(field1) <= [01/19/2018] , but not work. For some document, the field field1 is N/A, so I changed to FIELD @IsTime(field1) AND FIELD @TextToTime(field1) >= [01/01/2018] AND FIELD @TextToTime(field1) <= [01/19/2018] , but doesn't work yet. Any suggestion?

Comment: Ooops.  This is FT search syntax! We can't use @TextToTime or other normal formula language constructs here. D.Bugger's suggestions are the way to go.